# How to call all elements even if one fails when using try?

Tags: javascript

```js
try {
document.querySelector("div[role='banner']").remove()
document.querySelector("div[aria-label='start']").remove()

document.getElementById("container").children[0].style.left = '0px';
document.getElementById("container").children[0].style.top = '300px';
document.getElementById('container').children[0].style.width  = '828px';
document.getElementById('container').children[0].style.height = '466px';
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

I one of the documents above fails, the others are not executed, how i could execute all even if one of them fails?

Theres no other option than calling each one inside of a `try` block?

Comment: Simply don't wrap them in the same `try` block. A `try` block means you want to stop as soon as an error occurs. If you don't mean that, don't do that. Separate into multiple `try` blocks if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Use optional chaining instead of `try`, which will simply stop the statement on that line rather than throwing an error in case one of the values on the left is nullish. You can also check to see if the child exists by storing it in a variable before assigning to its style.

```
document.querySelector("div[role='banner']")?.remove()
document.querySelector("div[aria-label='start']")?.remove()
const child = document.getElementById("container").children[0];
if (child) {
  Object.assign(
    child.style,
    { left: '0px', top: '300px', width: '828px', height: '466px' }
  );
}
```

That said, this sort of code is a bit of a code smell. Consider if you could toggle a CSS class on a parent element instead, and then apply the styles as needed (`display: none` and the left/top/width/height).

Comment: The only issue with this is that it doesn't tell you if an error occurred. But then maybe OP doesn't really need that anyway...